Defining Directional Loads of Bearing on Housing Bores
I am working on a gearbox model in Abaqus CAE, where bearings are seated in bores on the housing. I need to apply forces in three directions (x, y, z) on the inner surface (highlighted) of the bores (bore diameters), as shown here.

I am unsure how to define these loads correctly using Abaqus CAE. Should I use the GUI or scripting, and which type of load would be most appropriate for this situation?
So far, I have attempted applying concentrated loads on node sets. These sets were created by selecting nodes on the inner surface of the bores, and the loads were defined in three directions. However, I am uncertain whether this approach is realistic or accurate, because the results seem not right!
Any insights or suggestions on how to handle this would be greatly appreciated!
